# Walk MRO for Python special methods returning NotImplemented

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

I have a hierarchy of classes for algebraic objects that implement special methods such as `__mul__` and `__add__`, and use multiple inheritance. I was somehow assuming that Python (>= 3.5) would walk the method-resolution order (mro) to find the first method that does not return `NotImplemented`. Alas, this does not seem to be the case. Consider the following minimal example:

```
class A():
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return "A * %s" % other

class B():
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return "B * %s" % other
        else:
            return NotImplemented

class C(B, A):
    pass

class D(B, A):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        res = B.__mul__(self, other)
        if res is NotImplemented:
            res = A.__mul__(self, other)
        return res
```

In this code, I have implemented `D` with the desired behavior:

```
>>> d = D()
>>> d * 1
'B * 1'
>>> d * "x"
'A * x'
```

However, I actually would have expected `C` to behave the same as `D`, which it does not:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c * 1
'B * 1'
>>> c * "x"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-23-549ffa5b5ffb>", line 1, in <module>
    c * "x"
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'C'
```

I understand what's happening, of course: I'm just returning the result of the first matching method in the mro (I'd just hoped that `NotImplemented` would be handled as a special value)

My question is if there's any way to get around writing the boilerplate code like `D.__mul__` (which would be basically the same for all the numerical special methods, for all the classes). I suppose I could write a class decorator or metaclass to automatically generate all these methods, but I was hoping there would be some easier (standard library) way, or alternatively, that someone has already done something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python walks up MRO when you ask it to, it's not implicit to keep checking higher. Change your code to use cooperative inheritance with `super()` (a request to walk the MRO to the next class up) when you would otherwise return `NotImplemented` and it should work. It removes the need for either `C` or `D` to define `__mul__` at all, since they don't add anything to its functionality:

```
class A():
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return "A * %s" % other

class B():
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return "B * %s" % other
        try:
            return super().__mul__(other)  # Delegate to next class in MRO
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented  # If no other class to delegate to, NotImplemented

class C(B, A):
    pass

class D(B, A):
    pass  # Look ma, no __mul__!
```

Then testing:

```
>>> d = D()
>>> d * 1
'B * 1'
>>> d * 'x'
'A * x'
```

The magic of `super()` is that it works even in multiple inheritance scenarios where one class, `B` in this case, knows nothing about `A`, but will still happily delegate to it (or any other available class) if a child happens to inherit from both. If it doesn't, we handle the resulting `AttributeError` to make the result `NotImplemented`, as before, so stuff like this works as expected (it tries `str`'s `__rmul__` which doesn't recognize non-`int` and explodes):

```
>>> class E(B): pass
>>> e = E()
>>> e * 1
'B * 1'
>>> e * 'x'
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'E'
```

Comment: Yup, that's it! Makes perfect sense once you see it!